# Why can't I nest an if exist statement inside this code in a batch/cmd file

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, command-line, cmd

I am currently writing a short command line utility to quickly install/uninstall programs and need to first identify that installation files exist to give a meaningful error message in the event that conditions aren't met.

I currently have the below code written

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions

echo.
echo 1.Run Program1
echo 2.Summit else
echo 3.Summit else
echo 4.Summit else
echo 5.Summit else
echo.

set /p a= Enter Choice: 

if %a%==1(
if exist program1.cmd(
    rem program1 exists
    echo "Run program1.cmd"
    ) else(
    rem program1 does not exist
    echo "program1 does not exist"
    ))
pause
```

I am currently told "The syntax of the command is incorrect." regardless of whether Program.cmd exists or not but I don't understand why.

Is nesting if commands not possible in batch/cmd files or do I fundamentally misunderstand something in the syntax of windows command-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to nest `if`/`for` commands, but `cmd` is **very very very** picky about space - one less or more space can crash the script easily.

Here is the fixed code.

```
if "%a%"=="1" (
    if exist program1.cmd (
        rem program1 exists
        echo "Run program1.cmd"
          ) else (
        rem program1 does not exist
        echo "program1 does not exist"
    )
)
```

Please review the differences between mine and yours `if` statement syntax. Also, `if %a%==1` can be *(and should be, not mandatory)* changed to `if "%a%"=="1"` for safer comparison.

Why should we change to use quotes(`"`)? Consider you accidentally inputted a space. `CMD` will see this:

```
if  ==1 (
```

which it doesn't understand.

Comment: I'll take your advice to heart, this problem has been bugging me for the last half an hour, thanks.